# Want to add Searchbar on navigation bar when search button is clicked on navigation bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, navigationbar

I am Using UItableView controller , i am not able to add searchbar to navigation bar . i want searchbar to come when search button on navigation bar is clicked. How to add search button and search bar on navigation bar .

Comment: Are you using storyboards or have it in code?

Comment: I am using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

add this at button click => .m file:

```
 UISearchBar  *sBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.width,self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height/2)];
sBar.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:sBar];
```

and add this => .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

to make searchbar like this you want to insert Button in Navigation bar controller and set background image as `search.png`(your image). so, when user click on this button set target as `searchbar`will be open. please check below code for your reference.

First of all set delegate method in you `.h` file.

```
@interface FriendsViewController : UIViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *searchButton;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *searchItem;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchBar *searchBar;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchDisplayController *d1;
```

then Insert button in your nevigationbar.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(279,9,25, 25)];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search"] //put here your searchimage
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickme:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barbtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn];
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barbtn;
[self.tabBarController.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
```

Now you have to set searchcontroller on `clickme` your button method.

```
- (IBAction)clickme:(id)sender{
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44.0)];
searchBar.autoresizingMask =0;
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.placeholder = @"Search for items...";
searchBar.showsScopeBar=YES;

UIView *searchBarWrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
searchBarWrapper.autoresizingMask = 0;
[searchBarWrapper addSubview:searchBar];

self.searchItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBarWrapper];
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.searchItem;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;

  ////////////// ~ Search Display Controller as Object ~/////////////////////////////

self.d1 = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
self.d1.delegate = self;
self.d1.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.d1.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.d1.searchResultsTableView.rowHeight = 40;
self.d1.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
self.searchBar.translucent = NO;
self.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
self.d1.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

[searchBar sizeToFit];

}
```

[image: Barbutton]

when you click on search icon

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For search button you can use UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch if need.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(actionSearch:)];
```

and you can set searchbar as title view of navigationbar

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = mySearchBar;
```